# After update masterpage framework 4.0 is very busy

Tags: asp.net, performance, frameworks, compilation, master-pages

I have a problem with changing the masterpage file (asp.net). After update (the file size is only 150 kB), the processor starts to compile a very long time (10 minutes or more), the processor has nearly 100% utilization, server memory will increase significantly. Web server then responds slowly, continuously compiles, processor extracts the maximum. After compiling the server remains very busy, so the web is essentially unavailable.
Sometimes after restarting the web server comes after 2 hours to a standard web service and response very quickly. Once it changes the masterpage, will again long time to compile a significant slowdown.

Masterpage refers to no other resources or dll library, which should slow down the compilation. This situation is lasts 14 days before the web to function normally! With every changes masterpage the web is slower.

I tried to reinstall the framework, clean Temporary ASP.NET
Files, debug processor and memory. In web.config: compilation debug="false"
Framework is 4.0.3, server is 2003, hardware is OK.

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: Very long time answer from web server - web processor has big utilization (process w3wp) after compile masterpage (a few hours).

Comment: Can you post your master page aspx & code behind?

Comment: It seems like you need to narrow down where the problem lies.  Do you have any profiling tools at your disposal, to see where the slowdown actually is?  How do you know that it has to do with "compiling" the MasterPage changes?

Comment: There is not problem in pages (masterpage). We try to reinstall FW and situation is better. Compilation is finished during 2 minutes, what is normal. 3 days the web server worked very well, but now the web server began to compile every (about) 5 minutes! Pages are still same, no update, but web compiles while running normally and again compiles ...

Comment: I maybe know, where is problem. In the event log: Event Source: ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0, It is not possible to run two different versions of ASP.NET in the same IIS process. Please use the IIS Administration Tool to reconfigure your server to run the application in a separate process. From this event FW starts often compilation. I have one bigger iis app and inside I have next small iis app. But none of them running in FW 2.0. All in 4.0. I do not know if fw have some ini file, where this information can be entered.